# .htaccess redirect to 404 page if anything is written after a .php file in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my website url `http://www.example.com/about-us.php` and if anybody tries to open `http://www.example.com/about-us.php/about-us.php` it should redirect to a 404 error page, rather it shows the same page (not with proper css styles). And this is just one example, there are more URLs like that. Is there are way to prevent these fake URLs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any framework or CMS, Or its just code php code?

Comment: and whats in your .htaccess file

Comment: Have you done anything in your .htaccess file

Comment: there is no htaccess file and it's core php